# Billing Geocode fields empty with BillingAddress populated

Tags: geocoding

I have data loaded some accounts with BillingAddress populated (including street, postal code), looking at the dev console... those records don't have any values in the BillingLat or BillingLong columns.

Is there a reason why or a setting we need to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://idealistconsulting.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/CleanRules/home) is not entirely clear on this, but you need to go to Setup > Data Integration Rules to enable the standard geocoding functions.